# malloc(): mismatching next->prev_size (unsorted)

Tags: c++

After trying several ways to erase specific pointers from a vector, now I get this error.
I'm using a double for loop to find the objects I need to erase. I'm doing something like this:

```
for(i=0; i<vectorfromClassA.size();i++){
    for(j=0; j<vectorfromClassB.size();j++){

         if(condition == true){
            delete vectorfromClassA[i]->vectorfromClassB[j];
            vectorfromClassA[i]->vectorfromClassB[j] = nullptr;
         }

    }
}
```

And then I'm using the erase-remove idiom like this after I finish to iterate class B vector:

```
vectorfromClassA->vectorfromClassB.erase(
    remove_if(
        vectorfromClassB.begin(), 
        vectorfromClassB.end(), 
        [](classB * b){return b == nullptr}));
```

After that, I can print the vector, but the error appears equally. If don't use the erase-remove, I can add new values to my vector, but the new value that I've tried to add appears twice. I think this could be because of the memory space from the vector is still there if don't erase it.

Can anyone help me to see the light?
Thank you and forgive me if I'm asking anything too obvious, as I said in my first post I'm new with all this stuff.

Comment: That error looks like your heap is corrupted. This can be caused by a large number of things, and it's not necessarily clear from what you posted what the cause is. The problem may be caused by an error that is far from where you experience difficulties. Please post a [MCVE] if possible.

Comment: I don't get why vectorFromClassB appears to be both a global and a member of class A.

Comment: vectorfromClassB is an attribute of classA, so every element on vectorfromClassA has a vectorfromClassB. And every vector's element is a pointer to class A or class B